# Java Class with multiple methods that can be executed in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java multithreaded programming. I have a use case where I have a runnable class called `Diner` and based on the state of different variables in the program, I want to execute different methods of the `Diner` Class in parallel.
One way to do that would be to have a single run() method containing multiple if conditions corresponding to different code blocks you want to execute as shown below.

```
    public class Diner implements Runnable  {
        Order order;
        int arrivalTime;



        public void run () {
            if(!isSeated){
                //do something to get a seat
            }
            if(!notEatenYet){
                //place order
            }
            if(!orderHasArrived){
                //start eating
            }
            if(finishedEating){
                //pay bill and leave
            }
        }
    }
```

However, is there a more elegant way to do this? Like rather than having a single `run()` method that can be parallelized, have different methods in the class that could be parallelized (overloading `run()` ?).

I believe I can use Akka Actors to accomplish something like this, but I am looking for a native solution.

Comment: have you refered this http://crunchify.com/how-to-run-multiple-threads-concurrently-in-java-executorservice-approach/

Comment: @RajithPemabandu the article that you have referred is just using the `ExectutorService` to launch and manage multiple threads rather than creating a separate `Thread` object for each of them. All the threads that are created have only one task that needs to be performed in parallel i.e Ping the hosts. And that is not what my question is referring to.

Comment: do you really want to run methods of the class in parallel? I can hardly imagine a diner which simultaneously gets seated, eats, and pays bill: this actions are strictly sequential.

Comment: What I meant to do say was there are multiple Diners in the system and therefore many of them could be waiting to get seated, ordering, eating simultaneously, hence the need for multiple tasks that could be "executed in parallel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to multi-threading consider easing into it gradually. Start with a single worker thread and post all your diner's tasks to this one thread.  This provides some concurrency - submitting tasks to the thread does not block - but eliminates many of the complexities of having multiple threads accessing the same Diner at the same time (synchronization, risk of deadlock, risk of race conditions etc)

Here is an example using a single thread scheduled executor.  It schedules some events to happen at 2, 4 and 6 seconds, but the calling thread does not block waiting for each event (although I do add an artificial block at the end with the countdown latch, so we can shutdown the executor cleanly)

```
public class Diner {

    public void findSeat() {
        System.out.println("findSeat");
    }
    public void placeOrder() {
        System.out.println("placeOrder");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final Diner diner = new Diner();

        exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                diner.findSeat();
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                diner.placeOrder();
            }
        }, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                done.countDown();
            }
        }, 6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        done.await();
        exec.shutdown();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Also there is no need for your Diner to implement Runnable.  Just create temporary
 runnables as necessary for each task.

When you need additional concurrency add a second, third executor service.  If you
 have tasks which are "stateless" - such as a database query - you could add a new
 executor service with multiple threads to get better parallelism.  Just make sure that
 when you update your diner your db threads do so by scheduling a task to the Diner
 executor, instead of modifying diner directly.

This would give you an Akka-esque style, but just using native Java utilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class SOCLass {

    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("method1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SOCLass clazz = new SOCLass();

        Runnable task1 = () -> { clazz.method1();};      
        Thread t1 = new Thread(task1);
        t1.start();

        Runnable task2 = () -> { clazz.method2();};      
        Thread t2 = new Thread(task1);
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I think for your case this approach would work better. You could launch the threads in a launch task method after evaluating the boolean. Just one Diner instance

Just keep the threads in place where you can control them

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, for your case, simple inheritance can be a good option.

you can have several sub-classes inheriting `Diner`,

So there would be one Diner abstract class and several sub classes,

```
public abstract class Diner implements Runable{
    public Order order;
    public int arrivalTime;
}

public class NotSeatedDiner extends Diner {
    public void run () {
        // do something to find a seat
    }
}
```

// some other subclasses

in your main function, you can have

```
List diners = new ArrayList<Diner>();

//maybe some factory producing different diners

diners.add(fac.getDiner("not seated"));

for(Diner diner : diners){
    diner.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create two classes and call start method(basic idia)
look at the example!

//class Second

```
public class Second extends Thread {
public void run() {
    for (int c = 100; c > 0; c--) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

}

//class Main

```
public class Main extends Thread {
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Main thread_1 = new Main();
    Second thread_2 = new Second();

    // Let's fix concurrency problem
    // method 1:
    
    thread_1.start();
    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.start();
    thread_2.join();
    
    //method 2:
   //or you can use  is alive
   /* thread_1.start();
    while (thread_1.isAlive()){
        System.out.print("");
    }thread_2.start();*/
    

}
```

}